# Create a limited Linux (ssh) login/user with read access to only one file

Tags: linux, limited-user-account

I'm creating a hacking challenge as a project in university.

Somewhere in the middle of the challenge the challengers will receive a user name "guest" and a password to enter one of my Linux virtual machines (via ssh).

I want this "guest" to be able to read only **one specific file** (just read and not to modify or delete), and I also want to make sure this user can't write, read, create, delete or modify any other directories and files (except that one specific file I had mentioned before).

How do I create such a user and such a file?

Comment: A useful resource is this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/149404/how-can-i-create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders . Also there exist restricted versions of shells rsh rbash rzsh etc if a sftp chroot is too restricted.

Comment: @hyph thank you for this resource. The meaning of this stage is using grep/find correctly to find the specific file, so I guess that sftp is too restricted to me. I will have a look at the shells you have mentioned above, thanks.

Comment: [Read this](https://superuser.com/q/1164042/432690).